# Avoiding explicit record typing

Tags: record, sml, smlnj

Suppose I have the following functions for operating over an idealized stream:

```
fun Stream s = { pos = 0, row = 1, col = 0, str = s }
fun len { str, pos = _, row = _, col = _ } = String.size str

fun poke off { str, pos, row: int, col: int } =
  let val n = pos + off in
    if n >= 0 andalso n <= (String.size str) then SOME (String.sub(str, n)) else NONE
  end
```

This works/compiles, but it's unfortunate to have to litter my function definitions with information I don't care about. `row`/`col` are ignored `poke` and `len`. However, while the wildcard can be used with `len`, it can't be with `poke`. Is there a way to restructure these functions so that less explicit typing needs to be put in, while still being able to pattern match/destructure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give your type a name (such as `stream`), you can refer to it more briefly:

```
type stream = { pos : int, row : int, col : int, str : string }

fun Stream s = { pos = 0, row = 1, col = 0, str = s }

fun len ({ str, ... } : stream) = String.size str

fun poke off ({ str, pos, ... } : stream) =
  let val n = pos + off in
    if n >= 0 andalso n <= String.size str
    then SOME (String.sub (str, n))
    else NONE
  end
```

Or, more-or-less equivalently:

```
datatype stream = STREAM of { pos : int, row : int, col : int, str : string }

fun Stream s = STREAM { pos = 0, row = 1, col = 0, str = s }

fun len (STREAM { str, ... }) = String.size str

fun poke off (STREAM { str, pos, ... }) =
  let val n = pos + off in
    if n >= 0 andalso n <= String.size str
    then SOME (String.sub (str, n))
    else NONE
  end
```